# Android Volley nested requests which require both responses?

Tags: java, android, json, mobile, android-volley

I was trying to fetch JSON data from a URL but within the data is also another URL which has more information I want for my RecyclerView Adapter class but since within the onResponse method I cannot access variables outside of it and I believe its asynchronous which means it runs on a different thread so using global variables is not an option either.

So I'm looking for one request for one JSONObject + Another request for a JSONArray based off of 1st request "id" THEN have access to both JSON to manipulate and add to RecyclerView

Example JSON data for 1st request

```
{  
   "departures":{  
      "all":[  
         {  
            "service_timetable":{  
               "id":"(ID TO ANOTHER JSON URL)"
            }
          }
       ]
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to use Retrofit instead of Volley